# Angular Invalid Argument 'z,x,y' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to do a autocomplete input box. The Angular Material tutorial were simple buy it seems like it does not like the data I am getting from API.

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: X,Z,Y  for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

.ts file

```
formServer = new FormControl();
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.formServer.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value): string[] {
    const filterValue = value;
    return this.servers.filter(option => option.includes(filterValue));
  }
```

.html code

```
   <mat-form-field class="w-100">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Server" aria-label="Server" matInput [formControl]="formServer" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of servers | async" [value]="item">
            {{item}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

API responce

```
{"servers":["z","x","y"]}
```

Comment: do you mean  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions | async" [value]="item">

Comment: did you import `import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';` in your `main.ts` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you can do `this.servers.filter(//...` and not get build error, I'm assuming that `this.servers` is a plain array, not an observable/promise.

Therefore, ditch the async pipe here:

```
<!-- Instead of: <mat-option *ngFor="let item of servers | async" [value]="item"> -->
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of servers" [value]="item">
```

Comment: Great that did work. but autocomplete is still not working.
Any ideas ?